# What is the alternative tag to <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item> for Menu Items

Tags: android

I am using "false" tag to show Menu items in the given text style instead of showing in All Caps. But this tag is working only in above API level 14 devices only. I need this functionality in Below API level 14 also. Is there any another tag for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you do it programmatically? Setting the text as you like you might have the desidered behaviour.

Comment: I tried in XML as well programmatically.No change in result. Actually I am trying to set text as "Settings" but its displaying as "SETTINGS". Could you provide any sample code regarding this?

Comment: you can use something like this: menuitem.setText(str.toLowerCase()); where str is your SETTING and menuitem is your object. Sorry but this code is not tested as I do not have android on this PC.